# SPARK: one powerful machine Vs. several smaller machines

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-sql

I am using one single machine with 60GB memory and 32 cores, with Spark 1.6.1 on AWS EC2.

My data comprise large number of records, I would like to process a DataFrame that has the following simple schema, and it has 1,000,000,000 (one billion) records:

```
userID: Long
phrase: String
timestamp: Timestamp
```

I am doing some expensive chains of operations like groupBy, sort, filter... etc.

These operations are leading into large shuffles writes and reads, and caching the DataFrames or repartitioning it are not helping much.

I am finding difficulties in understanding why this is happening, knowing that the machine is capable to load the full data into the memory.

When I click on the executors tab on Spark UI, I see the follow:

[image]

Is this a normal view to see when I use a single powerful machine, or I missed configured my Spark cluster?

Is there any recommendations about what is the best configuration of Spark on EC2?

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to be more about Spark than Zeppelin notebooks. You are welcome to revert that edit if I read the question incorrectly.

Comment: I agree @cricket_007, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry if it sounds condescending but a data load that fits in memory is hardly a huge data set. The reason I am saying this, is that Spark is not built for small data loads and you are paying the overhead that's built into spark to enable it to handle large datasets and distributed environments. e.g. a group by usually means that data needs to be shipped to remote machines so and shuffle phase organizes the data for shipment and then read by remote machines that handle the partitions after the shuffle. In your case you see all this happening on a single machine.

Since everything fits in a single machine you may want to check alternatives solutions - read [this](http://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html) for example

That said, it seems you are not utilizing all the memory you have on the machine (Memory storage is 20G vs. 60G on the machine). Since it seems you are running Spark in local mode set the driver memory to something higher (`--driver-memory 56G` or something like that) also make sure to use `local[32]` so you'd get all the cores running